# gst-launch camera get wrong color space

Tags: colors, camera, debian, gstreamer, yuv

I am using the following command to review the Raspberry Pi camera with Tinker board(Tinker OS V2.0.8).

> gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !
>   video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=640,height=480 ! videoconvert !
>   autovideosink

But the colour of the images show green as below(suppose be white):

[image]

So what suppose be the problem?
Is there any way to adjust the colour-balance?

I'm guessing the problem is about the format of the output images, which gives `NV12` that makes image look greenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

Base on the tutorial https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/wiki/index.php?title=CSI-camera

After Tinker OS V2.0.8 using following command to stream video:

> gst-launch-1.0 rkcamsrc device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 isp-mode=2A
>   tuning-xml-path=/etc/cam_iq/IMX219.xml ! videoconvert !
>   video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1800,height=960 ! rkximagesink